# Where does the the_permalink() take you by default

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Click here</a>
```

This takes me to the index.php page

How do I change this in order to take me to another page?

Since you guys closed this. I will answer my own question:

## **The answer**:

What you put in the WP_Query post_type = '(POST TYPE HERE)'

You can make a page called:

```
"single-(POST TYPE HERE).php
```

So once you click the link. This will take you to the:
`"single-(POST TYPE HERE).php` page

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: @ValentinMercier I've obviously checked that. You haven't answered my question.

Comment: documentation is pretty clear about this. If you want to get a permalink by ID, use the get_permalink function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Comment: The answer: What you put in the WP_Query post_type = '(POST TYPE HERE)' You can make a page called "single-(POST TYPE HERE).php

So once you click the link. This will take you to the "single-(POST TYPE HERE).php page

Answer (score 1):

`the_permalink()` outputs the URL of the post currently being viewed in *the loop*. If you wanted to change the destination of the link then replace `<?php the_permalink();?>`.

**Refs:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink
- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop